# JS: determine amount of occurrences in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Is there a way to determine the number of times a letter occurs inside another string?

if not, can you determine the number of times a string is in an array

if you can do it with the array, how can you split 2 words, such as: **Hello, World!** into an array of 2 words, like this:

```
["Hello", "World"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  A simple one liner that comes to mind is

```
var numOccurrences = str.split("<char>").length -1
```

where  can be replaced with whatever character (or string) you want to test for

That will split the string on each occurrence and then take the length of the resulting array -1.  Which will tell you the number of occurrences.

If you want to do it while ignoring upper/lower case, you can use regex

```
str.match(/<char>/gi).length
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The number of times a letter occurs in a string

This can be found as follows:

```
"Hello World Hello World!".match(/e/g).length    // Will result in 2
```

/e/g is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches the letter 'e'. The 'g' stands for "global" and gets all the occurances in a string.

#### String in an array

This can be found as follows:

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["Hello", "World", "Hello", "World"],
    wordCount = 0,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i += 1) {    // Remember to optimise length call
    if (arrayOfStrings[i] === "Hello") {
        wordCount += 1;
    } 
}

console.log(wordCount) // This will log 2
```

Comment: Did you actually try this?  I got TypeError: Object Hello World Hello World! has no method 'matched' when I ran it in the console.  I think you want `match`

Comment: A typo—that is what comes of making your code more terse in the editor. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Be careful, if no matches are found, `match` returns `null`. So `'abc'.match('e').length` throws an error. Test the result before using it.